# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let us consider $z\in \mathbb C$; what is the condition on modulus of z in order that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$$
the series (zeta function?) converges?
For example, if $|z|=1$, the series diverges?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Answer to this can be googled in a second.

Comment: Is $|z|\geq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Riemann zeta function** or **Euler–Riemann zeta function**, $ζ(s)$, is a function of a complex variable s that analytically continues the sum of the infinite series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$ which **converges when the real part of s is greater than 1**

Comment: You might say why this is true.

Comment: I try a condition on modulus...